# How to prevent scrolling the page when scrolling from a specific div?

Tags: html, css, scroll

I have a html page with a scroll. On this main page I have a floating div with another scroll.

The problem is when I scroll from the floating div and the scroll is at the max (top or bottom), the scroll continues but on the main page.

So, how to prevent the main page to scroll when I'm scrolling the floating div to the max ?

Sorry for my bad english.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe something like this will help. It will make it so keyCode 40 (down arrow keyboard) will stop user from being able to scroll using keyboard.

```
<script>
$(document).keydown(
  function(e)
  {    
      if (e.keyCode == 40) {
          e.preventDefault(); // this is what stops user from being able to scroll
          // extra code here
      }
  }
);
</script>
```

So... IF down arrow is pressed, [prevent default behavior](https://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/); key #38 is up arrow.